# Add attribute to Laravel model

Tags: laravel

I have user model, and I want to add if this user is qualified or not, I have some query to determine that,

User.php

```
....

     public function getIsQualifiedAttribute($value)
     {
            return $this->qualified()->first() ? true : false;
     }
    
     public function scopeQualified($query)
     {
            return $query->where("years_of_experience",">=",5);
     }
```

and this is how I want to print it

```
{{$user->is_qualified}}
```

but I can't make it work, it keeps giving me wrong value.

Comment: what value does it keep giving you that is wrong?  because echoing a bool is not a great idea as it will only show a value when true `1` as false is `''` `null`

Comment: its always true, even theres false values (empty)

Comment: but how I can get for only one user, like I want to check if this user qualified or not

Answer (score 0):

Laravel accessors does not have parameter
try to change your method like this

```
 public function getIsQualifiedAttribute()
 {
        return $this->qualified()->first() ? true : false;
 }
```

Comment: its optional parameter,  even if I removed it same thing

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do another query to this same table if you already have the model instance you want to check an attribute for. Just have the accessor check the `years_of_experience` field of the model:

```
public function getIsQualifiedAttribute()
{
    return $this->years_of_experience >= 5;
}

{{ $user->is_qualified ? 'Y' : 'N' }}
```

With your current setup you are doing a query to the database to get the first record which has `years_of_experience >= 5` every time the accessor was hit. If **any** record in that table has `years_of_experience >= 5` that will return `true`.

Comment: Yes, but the idea I want to use scope, because I might add to the query

Comment: then use the scope when you need it for queries which is what it is for

Comment: The problem is its not working, the scope is working but the attribute is not, not sure what I am doing wrong